# jQuery fancybox - target specific div #id in iframe

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Is it possible to use fancybox to load a specifc div #id from another page rather than loading the whole page via an iframe?

For example I can use

```
 $('#link-whole').fancybox({
                'width'             : '80%',
                'height'            : '80%',
                'type'              : 'iframe',
            });
```

with

```
<a id="link-whole" href="somepage.html">link 1</a>
```

to load all of 'somepage.html' into the iframe but how would I load JUST the content from a div with the id "target" (for example)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If the page is on the same domain of the page that you are opening the fancybox on then you should be able to use the dataFilter option of [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to filter the returned data down to the target ID that you want.

```
$('#link-whole').fancybox({
    'width': '80%',
    'height': '80%',
    'type': 'ajax',
    'ajax': {
        dataFilter: function(data) {
            return $(data).find('#yourTargetID')[0];
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: perfect! thank you!!
Is there a way of accomplishing this if the target page is on another domain..?

Answer (score 4):

If the find method doesn't work for you, try `filter` on the line inside dataFilter object.

```
    return $(data).filter('#yourTargetID')[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could target the specific part of the page using beforeShow

```
                  function opendialog(mypage) {
                  var linktoopen=mypage ;
                    $.fancybox({                        
                    'autoScale': false,
                    'transitionIn': 'elastic',
                    'transitionOut': 'elastic',
                    'speedIn': 500,
                    'speedOut': 300,                    
                    'width'         :  800,
                    'height'        :   410,
                    'autoDimensions': false,
                    'centerOnScroll': true,
                    'scrolling'   : 'no',
                    'type' :  'iframe',
                    'href' : linktoopen,
                      beforeShow: function(){
                          $(".fancybox-iframe").css({
                          margin  : "-380px 0 0",
                         height:"790px"
                       });
                     }
                    });
                    }
```