# Can FancyBox open in a specific div instead of the entire browser?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Not sure if this is possible, but I thought I'd ask. Is it possible to open up content inside another div? Currently FancyBox opens up the content inside the entire browser's viewport, but I just want it to open up in a specific div.

So a specific use case, I have a large image that I want to show smaller images within the large image, instead of the whole browsers page.

Comment: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054673/jquery-fancybox-target-specific-div-id-in-iframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you've found a solution to this problem yet, but I've made some progress. I'm using version 2.1.5 and have been editing the jQuery itself. I first did a search and replace for 'body' and changed all those values to my specified div that I want this to open up inside of. Then look for the line "F.helpers.overlay" and find the option "el : $('html'), " and change 'html' to your specified div.

It's still opening up in the entire window, but I'm currently tweaking the css since that's what's controlling its positioning at this point. Hope this helps a bit

EDIT: Okay I've figured it out!

So I had to set the "position: relative" to my div that I'm placing fancybox inside of. Then I had to add these styles "yourContainer .fancybox-overlay-fixed { position: absolute; }" to override the "fixed positioning" which is causing fancybox to overlay over the entire window. If you followed the steps I typed above as well as these in my edit, it should work for you! Let me know if you have any questions.

Also, I'm aware this question is old, but I'm sure other people come across this looking for the same solution. Hope I was of some help to some of you who come across this at a later date

Answer (score 0):

Since version 3.0, you have the possibility to declare in which element you want to inject the fancybox.

Here is the doc: https://www.luciadallas.com/js/fancybox3/docs/

```
// Container is injected into this element
parentEl: "body",
```

If you want the fancybox being injected in a specific div with class `product-menu`, use this code:

```
parentEl: ".product-menu"
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, FancyBox has a large set of options and methods so that with some clever thinking you could probably accomplish this.

But it does sound like you could easily make something yourself for this use case, using some clever jquery.