# How to show some part of webpage in jquery fancybox?

Tags: jquery, html, fancybox

I am trying to show some part of  webpage in Jquery fancybox. The target webpage is same as the parent webpage. Whole page can be easily displayed in a fancy box but how can I show some part in Jquery fancy box.

**Jquery i am using is**

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#open').fancybox({}); 
});
</script>
```

**and html is**

```
<a id='open' class='iframe' href='/webpage/fancybox.html'>Click here</a>
```

Comment: i want to show a div block of the target page in fancybox

Comment: Please create an example in http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: took me 3 seconds to find this:[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054673/jquery-fancybox-target-specific-div-id-in-iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054673/jquery-fancybox-target-specific-div-id-in-iframe)

Comment: You could use `ajax` instead of `iframe`, check http://stackoverflow.com/a/10546683/1055987